# Question: How to get an array index id? in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-vue

Scenario: I have an array which possesses 4 object i need to display the index of the array can someone help me to do this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `<td>{{ index }}</td>`?

Comment: Please try to avoid using screenshots instead of pasted code in future. It makes it easier for those attempting to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as using `index` in your output:

```
<tr v-for="(items,index) in addedArray" :key="items.DataID">
    <td>{{ index }}</td>
    ...
```

You are already capturing the index in `v-for="(items,index) in addedArray"`.